# vagrant up doesn`t running Progress state: E_INVALIDARG VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed

Tags: vagrant

Here is cmd error, I can't understand where is error and I'm bumping on it again and again, can`t solve it.

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Preparing master VM for linked clones...
    default: This is a one time operation. Once the master VM is prepared,
    default: it will be used as a base for linked clones, making the creation
    default: of new VMs take milliseconds on a modern system.
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/bionic64'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "\\\\?\\C:\\HashiCorp\\boxes\\hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-bionic64\\1.0.282\\virtualbox\\box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "ubuntu-18.04-amd64_1574870798285_57998", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "11", "--disk", "C:/Users/\u256C\u044B\u0445\u0443/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu-18.04-amd64_1574870798285_57998/ubuntu-18.04-amd64-disk001.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting \\?\C:\HashiCorp\boxes\hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-bionic64\1.0.282\virtualbox\box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: E_INVALIDARG
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057) - One or more arguments are invalid (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 957 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Answer (score 11):

I experienced the same issue and solved it by changing VirtualBox's base VM folder:

1. Open VirtualBox
2. Go to `File -> Preferences`
3. In the General tab, change the **Default Machine Folder** path to an existing path.
4. Run `vagrant up` again

In my case VirtualBox's Default Machine Folder was still pointing to my external hard drive which was no longer connected. Manually importing the Vagrant downloaded .ovf file in VBox via `File -> Import Virtual Appliance` lead me to the above solution. Vagrant does the same thing under the hood.

Comment: All I have needed it`s just to change the Default Machine Folder to whatever you want, the obligatory thing was just to change it from default

Comment: This solved my problem.  Mine was pointed to "C:\Users\XXXX\VirtualBox VMS", while I was logged in as YYYY, and thus it needed to be "C:\Users\YYYY\VirtualBox VMs".  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue and stumbled for several hours. Finally, it worked from the following steps.

1. My C drive didn't have enough memory for the Vagrant to bring up the Virtual box. Cleared the memory for Vagrant. It all worked well without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

1. free enough space in your drive C :
2. make sure it's `C:\\HashiCorp\\boxes\\hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-bionic64\\1.0.282` up to date

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had follow the instructions to change the default machine folder to the same path as the one set for environment variable for VAGRANT_HOME

Open VirtualBox
Go to File -> Preferences
In the General tab, change the Default Machine Folder path to an existing path.
Run vagrant up again

Answer (score 0):

you can check PATH below,if has blank or special character, change it.

1. Vagrant install PATH
2. VirtualBox install PATH
3. $VAGRANT_HOME PATH
4. VirtualBox default Virtual Machine location PATH

Also, free enough space $VAGRANT_HOME and VirtualBox default Virtual Machine location