# Problems while running `vagrant up` command in GIT Bash

Tags: php, mysql, web, server, web-development-server

I'm new in PHP and MySQL programming, I have VirtualBox to create a web server on my PC for free with Homestead Improved, I found the instructions on a book. I cloned Homestead on my PC and in the same directory I tried to run `vagrant up`. Unfortunately, I got this error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\simon\\.vagrant.d\\boxes\\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead\\11.5.0\\virtualbox\\box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "ubuntu-20.04-amd64_1638456664386_25621", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "11", "--disk", "C:/Users/simon/Desktop/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu-20.04-amd64_1638456664386_25621/ubuntu-20.04-amd64-disk001.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting \\?\C:\Users\simon\.vagrant.d\boxes\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead\11.5.0\virtualbox\box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: E_INVALIDARG
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057) - One or more arguments are invalid (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 1119 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Can someone help me please? I'm going crazy.

Comment: Please check this answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074939/vagrant-up-doesnt-running-progress-state-e-invalidarg-vboxmanage-exe-error-a). They say that by changing VirtualBox's base VM folder, the problem is solved.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I put it in Desktop, Documents... it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vagrant up doesn\`t running Progress state: E\_INVALIDARG VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074939/vagrant-up-doesnt-running-progress-state-e-invalidarg-vboxmanage-exe-error-a)

Comment: It doesn't work